# Price for Music (commercial videos for web or TV)

Tags: music-business, prices, commercials, video, web

I know it's always a very subjective question, but I'm trying to find a fair and objective criteria to evaluate how much I should charge for music for video and web/TV Commercials.

Should I apply some kind of "rate per minute of music"? 
How much difference should I consider depending if it's music for a TV Commercial or for a video for "web business promo" (the video will only be watched online and shared via social networking or client's website)? 
Would you do some kind of measurement on the music's complexity (for example for how many tracks there are in the mix? To me sounds too much and complex elements to include in negotiation with my clients). 
Would you distinguish your price also by the final cient's? (for example: charging higher for bigger companies)

Let's assume that recording costs are irrelevant (either because I work 90% of the time with midi only material, or the audio I record for the music may be considered costless, or simply I know that if I'll have to pay extra XX$ for some recording, I'll add that plus maybe some margin to my final price). What I'm searching here is some kind of price for creativity and music composition itself, in the end.

Thank you.